# Unexpected behavior with opacity in mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I made some animation in the landing page. The heading is suppose to have the animation of slide-in from right.
So I've set the opacity of the heading to `0` and then it is again set to `1` after animation starts happening.
This works completely fine as expected in desktop view.
But in mobile view, the opacity is not being set to 1 at the time of animation and end up hidden-heading.

Check the link https://jakedvirus.github.io/

I'm desperately looking forward for help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on narrower viewports the `heroimage-2x.jpg` fails to load (error 404) which breaks the script responsible for showing the heading.

[image]